# USB Tethering doesn't work on my Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb

I am new in Linux usb Tethering doesn't work in my lubuntu pc please help how I fix it .
When i plug my phone into my pc it's show media manager but when i turn on usb Tethering then nothing happens even in network manager

Comment: "Does not work" is not specific. Does it show up in the network manager? Does it say connected, but you can't get to the internet? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/870904/edit) the question with more details.